# How to refer to somebody who answered a question?

Tags: word-usage, acronyms

On StackExchange websites I often read the *OP* acronym to talk about a person who asks a question.

How about the one who answers the question? How would I refer to them? Is there an acronym or a common expression?

I've read the *answerer* on some translation websites, is it recommended? What about the *replier*?

Answer (score 2):

There is no great, universal answer to your question. Sorry. "Answerer" works just fine though.

Answer (score 0):

What about the **replier** (like  Neil D'Silva suggests) ?

Comment: It sounds somewhat odd.

Answer (score 0):

I think respondent would be appropriate, as they are responding to the question(s) asked.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it primary opinion based question as there is no official term for that. Anyway, I'll go by logic.

I'd go for *Responder* though *Answerer* is often used. That's because at times, we don't get questions or in other words not everything asked here is question. It could be in terms of doubt, query or the like. So, we would **respond** it first.

We may use *original* here as well because anyone can edit the question/answer here.

It depends on the users how do they make it short.

Comment: The "original poster" term refers to the person who wrote the first post in a thread.  This sense of "original" doesn't apply to the people who respond, so "original responder" is rather odd-sounding.

Comment: *original answerer/responder* is also the person who first answered the question. *Bob, Tina and Mike* all responded (for them, it was **their first response** to the question but then snailplane, maulik and StoneyB edited their answers. In comments, snailplane stated that ORer or OA missed the article and thus it was corrected.

Comment: -1. I'm sorry, but I don't think the OP is looking for someone to invent a term that no one will understand.  (I've read your explanation and I'm still confused...)

Comment: Or just "responder" is an option.

Comment: @snailplane okay corrected

Comment: I don't agree with 'responder' at all. Response is not necessarily verbal or, in this case, in words. Even if a mosquito buzzes across your face and you blink your eyes, it is a response. The appropriate word here would be REPLIER. It is authentic, considering what we are giving out (or looking for) here are replies.

Comment: The very *identity* of StackExchange is that it is a collection of Question & Answer sites, not a Doubts & Responses site. I find it rather strange that a high rep user should claim that it is not always so.

Comment: @Happy Yes, it's not always so; because at times, the askers have doubts (doubt is different than a question, right?) wherein they have at least some idea for what they ask. I've also read some questions where the answer is already told by the asker (as a doubt!) and some native speaker would just *nod* and say -yes, you got it right.

Comment: That's a very unusual definition of 'doubt'. Nonetheless, what gets asked here is always a question. It doesn't matter if the asker has a "doubt" or even knows the answer. One cannot *ask* a doubt or an answer, one can only ask a question.

Comment: @Happy True. I can present my doubt and that's how a *response* would come **as an answer**!

Comment: @NeilD'Silva You should write an answer

Comment: @NeilD'Silva respond: to say or write something as an answer to a question or request. A "Response is not necessarily verbal" but it certainly can be, and "respond" and "reply" can certainly be considered synonymous. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/respond

Comment: @nxx Thanks for pointing that out. I voted you up. And yet, I stand by what I said earlier. 'Response' is a larger term than 'reply'. The former is the superset of the latter, a subset. Even a change in the surroundings, as I mentioned earlier, elicits a response. What we do here is much more specific. We answer questions, and hence they are replies. They are responses too, but they are specifically replies. I presume the asker needed a specific word.

Comment: I am not very sure what Maulik means and where this entire discussion between 'doubt' and 'question' is heading to. Doubt is something that arises in one's mind and it may very well remain there. However, a question is something that is asked. Barring rhetorical questions, I would say that every question arises from a doubt, but every doubt need not become a question. Definitely what we put down here in threads are questions, and they have come from our doubts. The distinction between the two is very clear.